# Would Like to place Time ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to append a time ticker based on 4Pm CT, request anyone with JQuery/JavaScript knowledge to help me

```
var now = new Date();//get local time
var hrs = 16-(now.getUTCHours()-5);// convert local to UTC and then CST and checks time differnce with 4CT
var min = 60-now.getUTCMinutes();
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gSRcN/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this using `setInterval`

http://jsfiddle.net/gSRcN/2/

Javascript

```
//ticker function that will refresh our display every second
function tick() {
    var now = new Date(); //get local time
    var hrs = 16 - (now.getUTCHours() -5); // convert local to UTC and then CST and checks time differnce with 4CT
    var min = 60 - now.getUTCMinutes();
    var sec = 60 - now.getUTCSeconds();
    if (min > 0) {
        hrs = hrs - 1;
    }
    document.getElementById('time_ticker').innerHTML = hrs + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
}


//the runner
var t = setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

HTML

```
<div id="primaryProductAvailability">
    <div class="short-message-block">   <span>Availability: </span><span class="message availability in-stock">In Stock</span>

    </div>
    <div class="long-message-block">    <span class="message in-stock">Ships same day if ordered before 4pm CT</span>

    </div>
</div>
<span id="time_ticker"></span>
```

I added the seconds to make the ticker look more lively.

Comment: can you kindly check this fiddle and let me know where actually im going wrong, i would like to replace the message. check this fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/gSRcN/8/

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/gSRcN/12/ you need to:1. you need jQuery
2. select onDomready
3. use the jquery .html() and not the Javascript .innerHTML()
4. to update the inner HTML use .html("...")
5. add one curly bracket at the end